# Chart.js 4.0.1 and requirejs

Tags: javascript, chart.js, requirejs

with chart.js 3.9.1 this statement was working:

```
const Chart = require('chart.js/auto').default;
```

I just updated to chart.js 4.0.1 and now I get the following error:

Module not found: Error: Package path ./auto is not exported from package node_modules/chart.js (see exports field in node_modules/chart.js/package.json)

Any hint?

Thank you

Stefano

Answer (score 1):

You must use `UMD` packages.

```
const Chart = require('chart.umd.js/auto').default;
```